# Textbox slides right on hover jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down menu with a list of services. I want a text box to slide on the right side of the drop down menu when I hover on to it.

How do  I do that efficiently?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-gb" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top logo"><b>Title</b></a>
                </div>
                <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
                       
                        <li class="dropdown" id="services-dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu w-100">
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't mention where the descriptive text should be, I assumed that your description text is to describe what the service is. Therefore, you can place a div to contain your description text inside the relative `li`, and add a hover event for the `service-item` to make the description text div visible by using sibling selector `~`.

Sibling selector `~` helps to select sibling element for the selector, you can refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator).

```css
.navbar{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  background-color:rgb(34,34,34);
}

.navbar-header a{
  color:rgb(153,153,152);
  font-weight:bold;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
}

#main-nav{
  display:flex;
  flex:1 0 auto;
}

.navbar-nav{
  display:flex;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type:none;
  align-items:center;
}

.nav>li{
  position:relative;
}

.nav>li>a{
  padding:10px 20px;
  color:#fff;
  background-color:rgb(8,8,8);
  display:block;
  text-decoration:none
}

.nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
}

.dropdown-menu{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  padding:15px 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
  list-style-type:none;
  top:100%;
}

.dropdown-menu a{
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  z-index:1;
  position:relative;
}

.dropdown-menu li:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.dropdown .description-text{
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  visibility:hidden;
  transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px #000;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.description-text p{
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
}

.dropdown li a:hover ~ .description-text{
  opacity:1;
  visibility:visible;
  transform:translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en-gb" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand scroll-top logo"><b>Title</b></a>
                </div>
                <div id="main-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="mainNav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="scroll-link">Home</a></li>
                       
                        <li class="dropdown" id="services-dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu w-100">
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 1</a>
                                <div class="description-text"><p>Description text slides right here.<p></div>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 2</a><div class="description-text"><p>Description text slides right here.<p></div></li>
                                <li><a href="#" class="service-item">Service 3</a><div class="description-text"><p>Description text slides right here.<p></div></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**You didn't include your css here, so I try replicate your style as much as I can. You can change to your desired style.**

Comment: It works perfectly. Just one thing if you can change it. The description box slides in front of the menu. Is it possible to make it come from behind?